# Issue with Uppy.ImageEditor plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, uppy

I'm trying to use the image uploader plugin called uppy.io(https://uppy.io/). And it is internally using an image-editor plugin(https://uppy.io/docs/image-editor/). so the issue that I'm facing while trying to use the `Uppy.ImageEditor` is it returns `Expected a plugin class, but got undefined.`  In the console. Any idea why that happens? below is the code that I'm using. Any helps would be appreciated.

```
var uppy = Uppy.Core()
    .use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
      inline: true,
      target: '#drag-drop-area',
      height: 300,
      metaFields: [
        { id: 'name', name: 'Name', placeholder: 'file name' },
        { id: 'caption', name: 'Caption', placeholder: 'describe what the image is about' }
      ]
    })
    .use(Uppy.Webcam, { target: Uppy.Dashboard })
    .use(Uppy.Instagram, { target: Uppy.Dashboard, companionUrl: 'https://companion.uppy.io' })
    .use(Uppy.ImageEditor, { 
        target: Uppy.Dashboard,
        id: 'ImageEditor',
        quality: 0.8,
        cropperOptions: { 
            viewMode: 1,
            background: false,
            autoCropArea: 1,
            responsive: true
        }
    })
    .use(Uppy.Tus, {endpoint: 'https://master.tus.io/files/'})
    
uppy.on('complete', (result) => {
    console.log('Upload complete! We’ve uploaded these files:', result.successful)
})
```

Comment: Best try the community forum and share how you are loading Uppy and its plugins, the full code.

Comment: What @kvz said. The forum is here https://community.transloadit.com/c/uppy/5

My concern is that maybe not all of the plugins you are using are imported correctly?

Comment: @kvz user511202, Thanks guys. I'll check there.

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**

Uppy does not allow this for CDN packages yet but we can implment this using react js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).